# How to get sum of mysql column using PHP as usable variable

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching for a week now on how to accomplish this but none of the tutorials have worked - I typically get a message "resource id 18."

I'm creating a bank simulation game.

End goal: I want a variable "$player_balance" to be the sum of all account balances owned by that player so that it can be displayed at the bottom of the table under account balances.

Here is my code, thanks for any help or direction that you can provide.

```
function displayMyAccounts(){
   global $database, $session;
   $q = "SELECT game_account_number,game_account_owner,game_account_name,game_account_balance FROM ".TBL_ACCOUNTS." WHERE game_account_owner='".$session->username."'";
   $result = $database->query($q);
   /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
   $num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);
   if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)){
      echo "Error displaying info";
      return;
   }
   if($num_rows == 0){
      echo "Database table empty";
      return;
   }

   /* Display table contents */
   echo "<table align=\"left\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" width=\"100%\">\n";
   echo "<tr><td><b>Account Number</b></td><td><b>Account Name</b></td><td><b>Balance</b></td></tr>\n";
   for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
      $anumber  = mysql_result($result,$i,"game_account_number");
      $aowner = mysql_result($result,$i,"game_account_owner");
      $aname  = mysql_result($result,$i,"game_account_name");
      $abalance   = mysql_result($result,$i,"game_account_balance");
      setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
      $abalance2 = money_format('%(#10n', $abalance);

      echo "<tr><td>$anumber</td><td>$aname</td><td>$abalance2</td></tr>\n";
   }
       echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>$player_balance</td></tr>\n";
   echo "</table><br>\n";
}
displayMyAccounts();
```

The above code is what appears on each player's "account page."  I want the sum of their accounts to appear on the last row.  Thanks for any help, I'll continue searching and trying in the meantime.

Here is the output based on the above:

```
    Account Number  Account Name    Balance
    1000083690  Maverick    $ 50,000.00
    1000083696  WellsFargo  $ 50,000.00
    1000083697  Wachovia    $ 50,000.00
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed the output from MySQL ... are you actually retrieving any information from your MySQL query?

Comment: It looks to me like you just need to add $abalance to $player_balance inside the loop that iterates over the query results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `mysql_result()`.  It's slow and inefficient, and what you're doing is better done with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`:

```
$player_balance = 0;
// Also, ditch the for loop. This is the typical convention for retrieving results.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $abalance1 = money_format('%(#10n', $row['game_account_balance']);
  echo  "<tr><td>{$row['game_account_number']}</td><td>{$row['game_account_name']}</td><td>$abalance1</td></tr>\n";

  // Now add to the balance
  $player_balance = $player_balance + $row['game_account_balance'];
}
// And output your balance
$abalance_sum = money_format('%(#10n', $player_balance);
echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>$abalance_sum</td></tr>\n";
```

Comment: @Kenny I made several changes above. It was probably because money_format outputs a string. I changed it to do the addition before performing `money_format()` both inside and outside the loop.

Comment: Trying to figure out what happened... I swapped the code and now the page is not appearing... Going to try a few things and may re-post the code based on your suggested changed.

Comment: @Kevin if the page is blank, there's a syntax error. Turn on `display_errors` and you'll see where it is:  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.  You should always do this when developing.

Comment: @Kevin I think I see it - `game_account_number` was missing it's `g`, though I wouldn't expect that to choke the whole thing, just issue a warning for an invalid variable.

Comment: @Michael.. Showing this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/kennyj/public_html/create_account.php on line 51   Line 51:   echo  "<tr><td>$row['game_account_number']</td><td>$row['game_account_name']</td><td>$abalance1</td></tr>";

Comment: @Kevin Enclose the `$row['']` vars in `{}` as `{$row['game_account_number']}`

Comment: Now I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/kennyj/public_html/create_account.php on line 68" which doesn't make sense to me because that line just includes my footer file.

Comment: @Kevin Your error is elsewhere then the code above when saved to a file and checked with `php -l` has no syntax error.  Somewhere probably is an unclosed `{}` or `()`

Comment: Wow... Could not find a missing bracket... Reverted back to old code so I could finish up some other things.  I am pretty new to all of this and have no idea how to debug.. Pretty much have learned by trial and error.  So far I am not finding an easy way to debug.  I use notepad++ for everyone.  But thanks for your help on this, it did provide good information to use going forward.

Answer (score -1):

resource error means 
 YOU DO NOT HAVE THE TABLE OR THE PERMISSION, OR YOU ARE TRY TO ACCESS A COLUMN WHICH DOES NOT EXIST

Comment: I'm sorry... IT says resource id 18. I have all permissions and the table exists.  Will update my post.